# attempt to index global 'Variable' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, runtime-error, garrys-mod

I've read some other answers to this and I understand that I am trying to access a variable that has not yet been assigned. However from what I can see, I have assigned it already. My Lua isn't the best, and maybe I just don't understand scoping properly yet, but could anyone explain why I am getting this?

```
include( "/vgui/cs_f4_menu.lua" )
AddCSLuaFile( "/vgui/cs_f4_menu.lua" )

local function openMenu()
    if(!CSF4Menu) then
        CSF4Menu = vgui.Create( "cs_f4_menu")
        CSF4Menu:SetVisible( false )
    end

    if(CSF4Menu:IsVisible()) then
        CSF4Menu:SetVisible( false )
        gui.EnableScreenClicker(false) --Here
    else
        CSF4Menu:SetVisible( true )
        gui.EnableScreenClicker(true)
    end
end

hook.Add("PlayerBindPress", "F4MenuBind", function(ply, bind, pressed)
    if string.find(bind, "gm_showspare2", 1, true) then
        F4Bind = input.KeyNameToNumber(input.LookupBinding(bind))
        openMenu()
    end
end)
```

vgui/cs_f4_menu.lua

```
scr_width = surface.ScreenWidth()
scr_height = surface.ScreenHeight()

box_width = math.floor(surface.ScreenWidth()*0.7)
box_height = math.floor(surface.ScreenHeight()*0.7)

local PANEL = {
    Init = function( self )
        self:SetSize( box_width, box_height )
        self:Center()
        self:SetVisible( true )
    end,

    Paint = function(self, w, h)
        surface.SetDrawColor(255, 255, 255, a=150)
        surface.DrawRect( 0, 0, w, h)
        surface.DrawOutlinedRect(2, 2, w-4, h-4)
    end
}

vgui.Register( "cs_f4_menu", PANEL)
```

The exact error I am getting is:

```
[ERROR] addons/darkrpmodification/lua/darkrp_modules/tpr_f4menu/cl_core.lua:14: attempt to index global 'CSF4Menu' (a nil value)
1. openMenu - addons/darkrpmodification/lua/darkrp_modules/tpr_f4menu/cl_core.lua:14
2. fn - addons/darkrpmodification/lua/darkrp_modules/tpr_f4menu/cl_core.lua:29
3. unknown - addons/ulib/lua/ulib/shared/hook.lua:109
```

But again I don't fully understand why. I had to move my include statement out of the function because I assumed that the local function couldn't find a file out of scope?

Comment: You're probably getting `nil` from `vgui.Create`.

Comment: @luther I figured that from the fact it wasnt callable. But why?

Comment: I didn't see the garrys-mod tag earlier. I'm not familiar with that, so I don't have a clue.

Comment: your code should not even come that far. `if(!CSF4Menu) then` will cause an error as ! is not a Lua operator. correct: `if not CSF4Menu then`

Comment: @Piglet Garry's mod isn't Lua, it [adds various C-like operators](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Specific_Operators).

Comment: @nobody ok didn't know that. looks like a stupid idea to me. it's like asking your new girlfriend to laugh like your ex because you're used to it.